# Resonance Structures for mCPBA

Tags: resonance

Is this a valid resonance structure?

[image]

I.e. can oxygen donate to positive carbon (i.e. are all oxygens sp2 hybridized)? If not, then why?

Comment: Oxygen *can't* donate to oxygen, are you even serious with this last bit?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an oxygen atom adjacent to a carbocation «can lend» electrons.  Similar to the mesomeric formulae drawn by you, one can equally formulate formulae for instance about ethyl acetate:

[image]

The charged structure to the right contributes less to the present state, than the first one to the left because the form with separated charges is higher in energy, than the uncharged one.

Regarding the hybridization and a difference of the oxygen atoms in an ester vs. for instance the oxygen in diethyl ether

[image]

count the number of non-bonding electron pairs of the atom in question which are *not moved* drawing mesomeric formulae.  Then add the number of $\sigma$ bonds between this particular atom, and adjacent atoms bound;

- if the sum equals to two, the atom formally is $sp$ hybridized
- if the sum equals to three, the atom formally is $sp^2$ hybridized
- if the sum equals to four, the atom is formally is $sp^3$ hybridzed

Hence: in diethyl ether, consider the oxygen as $sp^3$ (similar: water, alcohols); but in esters both oxygen atoms as $sp^2$.

The last structure depicted by you (lower row to the right) however is wrong.  Atoms up and including neon can not extend their valence shell beyond an octet (a bit different to e.g., S/P in the next period).